# How can I replace the bus in my breaker panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Would like to replace the interior bus bar assembly for a Siemens G2040MB1200 load center. Loadcenter is full and the back box is in a finished wall so replacing interior bus assembly is the desired path. Is there a part # for this application and is it available for purchase?

Comment: A bit of an x/y question... What's your real goal? What is this replacement trying to accomplish? There may be other ways to get the same result.

Comment: Can you upload a picture showing the current panel/breakers?

Comment: Drywall repair is easy and cheap compared to probably very little gain in terms of spaces, unless the back box is *vastly* oversize for the present guts, *.vs.* just putting in a subpanel (getting as many extra spaces as you like) with a little drywall repair.

Comment: That's probably a small box. Assuming (as *should* be the case) that there isn't anything significant in the wall above or below the panel, you can probably slap a panel immediately above or below it. Only catch will be if the panel is low and the feed is from the top or the panel is high and the feed is from the bottom, because you really don't want to move the service feed cables if you don't have to.

Comment: What is driving the bus of this replacement? Did the existing interior assembly get damaged somehow?  Or is the panel being full the main issue here?

Answer (score 4):

OK, so no matter how much you want it to be so, the fact is that panel interiors are not designed to be interchanged universally like that.  You can swap interiors on contemporary-to-each-other panels with the same box number, but you'll need to find one **of your panel's age** that fits that box.  That panel is probably too old for you to encounter one at retail - the "G"s are long gone from [Siemens' catalog](https://assets.new.siemens.com/siemens/assets/api/uuid:337a8594-9627-4af2-94a2-0b79f2182c40/sie-sa-espl-sel-app-guide.pdf) as far as I can see.

What you can do is use one of [Eaton's retrofit interiors](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/low-voltage-power-distribution-controls-systems/load-centers/ch-load-centers/retrofit-interior-kits-sa00406001e.pdf), which are specifically designed for this application (or to be more precise, FPE and Zinsco panels).  They include a fully adjustable interior and a universal cover.

However if you go with an Eaton BR or CH interior (more breaker spaces on CH), you will need to replace all your breakers (except for any BR breakers which were improperly placed in your panel). Breakers are not interchangeable across types.  That's why there are types.